# Codeigniter is not loading my view (404 Page Not Found)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a process countroller (process.php) with index function that lists all countries supported by the logged in user. Listed countries are hyperlinked to base_url()/process/$CountryCode (e.g. http://localhost/baseurl/process/us/).

process.php

```
class Process extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if ($this->uri->segment(2) != NULL) {
        $this->country();
    }
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('users');
    $data['country'] = $this->users->getSupportedCountriesByUserID();
    $data['title'] = 'Process';
    $this->load->view('process_view', $data);
}

public function country() {
    include 'country.php';
    $country = new Country;
    $country->index();
}
```

country.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Country extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        $data['process'] = $this->getProcesses();
        $data['category'] = $this->getCategories();
        $data['title'] = "Process | " . strtoupper($this->uri->segment(2));
        /*
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';
        */
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

If i uncomment the print_r, I get the data I need but in array form but has the '404 Page Not Found' below the output. It doesnt even load the 'welcome_message' view. Where did i go wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: change ur controller file's name first letter to uppercase

Comment: done. but same result. if i leave print_r commented, screen only shows 404 Page Not Found.

Comment: try to open with `http://localhost/baseurl/index.php/country.` added index.php after base url

Comment: still the same. http://localhost/baseurl/index.php/process/ loads fine and lists the countries but when I add a countrycode (http://localhost/gain/index.php/process/us/, it goes 404 Page Not Found

Comment: is this code valid?

`class Process extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if ($this->uri->segment(2) != NULL) {
        $this->country();
    }
}`

Comment: try with $this->uri->segment(3)

Comment: $this->uri->segment(2) is correct since if i check the data in the array, it shows the correct data. It just does not load any view afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your route properly, cause, you CI currently doesn't have a route, like `process/us`. This means as default: **process** controller and **us** method in it.

Forexample:

`$route['process/(:any)'] = 'process/country/$1`

And then, your country method will get `us` as the first parameter in the method.

Comment: But also I'm not suggest, to load one controller into another, it's going against basic MVC.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. Added route and removed the additional code from my constructor from process controller.